# Is there something wrong with using a hash function as a PRG?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-generator

I need to create cryptographically secure pseudorandomness in JavaScript. However, when I googled for PRGs, all I found was very sketchy.

My idea is as follows (in pseudocode):

```
seed = "0x1a29fd..." // long number I always get passed (impossible to guess but used in a different context as well)
hashedAndSaltedSeed = sha256sum("seed: " + seed)
purpose = "..." // my current function's name (no spaces)
usageIndex = 1; // will increment this each time

randomness = myPrg(hashedAndSaltedSeed, purpose, usageIndex)

function myPrg(hashedAndSaltedSeed, purpose, usageIndex, numberOfBytes) {
    if(numberOfBytes > 32) {
        fail()
    }

    input = purpose + " " + usageIndex + " " + hashedAndSaltedSeed
    return sha256sum(input).binary2hex().slice(0, 2*numberOfBytes).hex2binary()
}
```

I only need a small amount of randomness (at most 32 Byte at a time, very few times), so the speed difference won't matter. But is there anything else wrong with this approach?

The randomness I need doesn't need to be distributed perfectly randomly but it needs to be infeasible to guess the resulting randomness when only given `purpose` and `usageIndex` but not `seed` nor `hashedAndSaltedSeed`.

Edit: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention an important requirement. I'm sure it was in my question at some point as I wrote it but I seem to have deleted that part accidentally. I need to be able to reproduce the same randomness when given the same seed. That's why I can't just use something that gives me randomness but doesn't let me control the seed.

Comment: If `seed` is secret drawn uniformly at random from $2^{256}$ possibilities, that's fine, but your naming is a little confusing: what is the salt in `hashedAndSaltedSeed`?  This also, of course, begs the question of where `seed` comes from, but if your present goal is just to have a pseudorandom function family for which it is the caller's responsibility to choose a seed uniformly at random, then that's fine.

Comment: @kelalaka That won't work because I need to be able to reproduce the same randomness. (Sorry for not having mentioned this requirement in my initial question.)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage That's exactly how its drawn. :) The reason I don't wanna use it straight away or even its hash is that its also used as a key in a different part of the project. That's why I want to add some string that indicates my use case prior to hashing so that if I hand `hashedAndSaltedSeed` around, no one can do anything with it that it's not intended for. It's not technically a salt because it's constant. Maybe I should find a better name.

Comment: I would recommend having the number of bytes requested as an input to the final output function

Comment: You should make sure that the inputs are encoded uniquely.  As is, distinct inputs with spaces might get confused with one another and cause the same result.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean when the seeding triplets are written down by a human who doesn't know where one of them ends and the next one begins?

Comment: If I pass in `purpose="hello world"` and `usageIndex="foobar"`, I'll get the same key as if I pass in `purpose="hello"` and `usageIndex="world foobar"` even though the inputs are distinct.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Ah, okay. But this can't work for two reasons: Function names cannot contain spaces; usage indices are integers. I chose a space as the delimiter in the example because spaces do not occur anywhere in the input triplet.

Comment: I now changed the order of what goes into the hash function in case the hash function is vulnerable to a length extension attack.

Comment: Maybe use HMAC-SHA256 or HKDF-SHA256, with test vectors to confirm you're implementing them correctly, so you can simplify the job of auditors who will be wondering about uniquely encoded inputs and length extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fine, although you should avoid these conversions to and from hexadecimal, that are no needed and may introduce side channels.

Now, since you are using JavaScript, you can simply use the WebCrypto API. Specifically [crypto.GetRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues), which can fill an array up to 65536 bytes.

Comment: That's one of the libraries I came across when looking for one prior to asking. It doesn't let me control the seed, does it? (Sorry for not having mentioned this requirement in my initial question.)

Comment: @UTF-8 what amount of control do you need?

Comment: I need to be able to specify a seed. When I specify the same seed again, I need to get the same pseudorandomness out (all the calls will be exactly the same order and exactly the same ranges if different ranges / sizes are possible).

Answer (score 2):

In practice it is probably fine.

In theory - for anyone looking for the theoretical answer - hash functions only guarantee that collisions are infeasible to find by a PPT attacker while a PRG guarantees the output is indistinguishable from uniform randomness to a PPT attacker. The two are very different. Notably, a hash function can always output $0$ for the first $n/2$ bits and still be collision-resistant but if used for a PRG it would be trivially distinguishable in $O(n)$ time. A PRG is also supposed to be length-expanding whereas hash functions are often length compressing.

One-Way-Functions (OWFs), PRGs, and hash functions are all related. OWFs imply PRGs and vis-versa. A good practical hash function will probably be a PRG, as @fgrieu mentions in comments below.

Comment: The modern ideal for a hash is computational Indistinguishability from a random oracle.  SHA-3 is designed for (and believed to meet) that goal. SHA-2 is believed to meet (not designed for) that goal except for the length-extension property.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using a hash function, you used a block cipher, this would be precisely using CTR mode as a PRNG. This can definitely work, but I'd recommend you read [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/62887) to see some implementation details you'd want to be careful about (for the case of using a block cipher/AES).

Comment: This seems like a better idea than using a hash function. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you'll get better security with essentially no limits on the volume of data you can process if you use SHA-256, and less complexity of code to hash structured inputs like your purpose and usage index (as long as the inputs are uniquely encoded and prefix-free), _and_ you won't invite the standard timing side channel attacks that AES invites.  The performance may not be as good but that's probably not going to be your bottleneck here.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I can see that a random oracle would be better than an ideal cipher. But real hash functions might only produce multiples of 7 w/o violating the criteria of collision-resistant hash functions, or they might have other characteristics. Furthermore, ciphers are guaranteed to use the entire value space.

Comment: @UTF-8 That's why I said SHA-256 specifically, and not ‘a collision-resistant hash function’ generally.  (See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70709 for a more nuanced discussion.)  Use of the entire value space is actually part of what _weakens_ the security of, _e.g._, AES-CTR in contrast to ‘SHA256-CTR’ and why safe data volume limits are something you actually have to worry about for AES-CTR, unlike SHA256-CTR.